# Who are the angels mentioned in Luke 9:26?

Tags: angels, holy

> For whosoever shall be ashamed of me and of my words, of him shall the Son of man be ashamed, when he shall come in his own glory, and in his Father's, and of the **holy angels**. Luke 9:26 KJV

> ὃς γὰρ ἂν ἐπαισχυνθῇ με καὶ τοὺς ἐμοὺς λόγους, τοῦτον ὁ υἱὸς τοῦ ἀνθρώπου ἐπαισχυνθήσεται, ὅταν ἔλθῃ ἐν τῇ δόξῃ αὐτοῦ καὶ τοῦ πατρὸς καὶ τῶν **ἁγίων ἀγγέλων**. Luke 9:26 NAS28

How many of them and who are they?

Comment: They simply the angels of heaven.  Nothing more can be said because we are not told.

Comment: Sola Scriptura, according to the interpretation that the Protestant Reformation brought to what the Bible itself says as its self-definition, however, found in the Deuterocanon of the Old Testament: "I am Raphael, one of the **seven *holy angels*** ((ἁγίων ἀγγέλων), which present the prayers of the saints, and which go in and out before the glory of the Holy One".  Tob 12:15 KJA.  Does this open any window for book of Revelation?

Comment: "holy saints wilt thou turn? "  Job 5:1 LXX and ἀγγέλου ἁγίου Acts 10:22 NAS28, and seven angels  Revelation 8:2,3-4; 14:10.

Comment: Many do not accept the book of Tobit as part of the inspired canon of scripture.

Comment: Ok. The link between Tobias 12:15 and Revelation 8:2-4 exists only for some.

Answer (score 1):

We are not told anything about the identity of the "holy angels" in Luke 9:26.  However, they are described as "holy" presumably to distinguish them from the Devil's/Satan's angels as described elsewhere:

- Matt 24:41 - Then He will say to those on His left, ‘Depart from Me, you who are cursed, into the eternal fire prepared for **the devil and his angels**.
- Rev 12:7-9 - Then a war broke out in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon, and **the dragon and his angels** fought back. **8** But the dragon was not strong enough, and no longer was any place found in heaven for him and his angels. **9** And the great dragon was hurled down—that ancient serpent called the devil and Satan, the deceiver of the whole world. He was hurled to the earth, and **his angels with him**.

Other places also describe the angels of heaven:

- Rev 3:5 - Like them, he who overcomes will be dressed in white. And I will never blot out his name from the Book of Life, but I will confess his name before My **Father and His angels**.
- Matt 18:10 - See that you do not look down on any of these little ones. For I tell you that their **angels in heaven** always see the face of My Father in heaven.
- Matt 24:36 - No one knows about that day or hour, not even the **angels in heaven**, nor the Son, but only the Father.
- John 1:51 - Then He declared, “Truly, truly, I tell you, you will all see heaven open and the **angels of God** ascending and descending on the Son of Man.”
- Heb 12:22 - Instead, you have come to Mount Zion, to the **city of the living God**, the heavenly Jerusalem. You have come to **myriads of angels**

Comment: + 1 makes me wonder if there are "in-between" angels who are not exactly holy but also not evil either.